# Запуск desktop приложения службой из под пользователя SYSTEM

Tags: c#, служба

Имеется вот такой код, для запуска приложения.

```
#region Structures

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int Length;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public int cb;
    public String lpReserved;
    public String lpDesktop;
    public String lpTitle;
    public uint dwX;
    public uint dwY;
    public uint dwXSize;
    public uint dwYSize;
    public uint dwXCountChars;
    public uint dwYCountChars;
    public uint dwFillAttribute;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public short wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public uint dwProcessId;
    public uint dwThreadId;
}

#endregion

#region Enumerations

enum TOKEN_TYPE : int
{
    TokenPrimary = 1,
    TokenImpersonation = 2
}

enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL : int
{
    SecurityAnonymous = 0,
    SecurityIdentification = 1,
    SecurityImpersonation = 2,
    SecurityDelegation = 3,
}

#endregion

#region Constants

private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
private const int TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x1;
private const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x2;
private const int TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x4;
private const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x8;
private const int TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x10;
private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x40;
private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x20;
private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x100;
private const int TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x80;
private const int TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT);

//public const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
public const uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;
public const uint ALL = 0x001F0FFF;
public const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

public const int IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x40;
public const int NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20;
public const int HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x80;
public const int REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x100;

#endregion

#region Win32 API Imports

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hSnapshot);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public extern static bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandle, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
    String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool ProcessIdToSessionId(uint dwProcessId, ref uint pSessionId);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
public extern static bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess,
    ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, int TokenType,
    int ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

[DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess, ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern Boolean CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, Boolean bInherit);

const Int32 CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Launches the given application with full admin rights, and in addition bypasses the Vista UAC prompt
/// </summary>
/// <param name="applicationName">The name of the application to launch</param>
/// <param name="procInfo">Process information regarding the launched application that gets returned to the caller</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool StartProcessAndBypassUAC(String applicationName, out PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo)
{
    uint winlogonPid = 0;
    IntPtr hUserTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero, hPToken = IntPtr.Zero, hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
    procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

    // obtain the currently active session id; every logged on user in the system has a unique session id
    uint dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    // obtain the process id of the winlogon process that is running within the currently active session
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winlogon");
    foreach (Process p in processes)
    {
        if ((uint)p.SessionId == dwSessionId)
        {
            winlogonPid = (uint)p.Id;
        }
    }

    // obtain a handle to the winlogon process
    hProcess = OpenProcess(ALL, false, winlogonPid);

    // obtain a handle to the access token of the winlogon process
    if (!OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, ref hPToken))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return false;
    }

    // Security attibute structure used in DuplicateTokenEx and CreateProcessAsUser
    // I would prefer to not have to use a security attribute variable and to just 
    // simply pass null and inherit (by default) the security attributes
    // of the existing token. However, in C# structures are value types and therefore
    // cannot be assigned the null value.
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

    // copy the access token of the winlogon process; the newly created token will be a primary token
    if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hPToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, ref sa, (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification, (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, ref hUserTokenDup))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        CloseHandle(hPToken);
        return false;
    }

    // By default CreateProcessAsUser creates a process on a non-interactive window station, meaning
    // the window station has a desktop that is invisible and the process is incapable of receiving
    // user input. To remedy this we set the lpDesktop parameter to indicate we want to enable user 
    // interaction with the new process.
    STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = (int)Marshal.SizeOf(si);
    si.lpDesktop = @"winsta0\default"; // interactive window station parameter; basically this indicates that the process created can display a GUI on the desktop



    // flags that specify the priority and creation method of the process
    int dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;

    IntPtr pEnv = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref pEnv, hUserTokenDup, true))
    {
        dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
    }

    // create a new process in the current user's logon session
    bool result = CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDup,        // client's access token
                                    null,                   // file to execute
                                    applicationName,        // command line
                                    ref sa,                 // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                    ref sa,                 // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                    false,                  // handles are not inheritable
                                    dwCreationFlags,        // creation flags
                                    IntPtr.Zero,            // pointer to new environment block 
                                    null,                   // name of current directory 
                                    ref si,                 // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                                    out procInfo            // receives information about new process
                                    );

    // invalidate the handles
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    CloseHandle(hPToken);
    CloseHandle(hUserTokenDup);

    return result; // return the result
}
```

Само приложение является [Oculus Driver Runtime for Windows v 0.8.0.0](https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/pc/0.8.0.0-beta/Oculus_Runtime_for_Windows/). А более точнее, OculusConfigUtil.exe, который представляет из себя некий лаунчер, с минимальными настройками и отображением состояния самого драйвера, шлема Oculus и сервиса (OVRServiceLauncher.exe).

Вся специфичность вопроса заключается в том, что при вышеуказанном методе лаунчер выдаёт сообщение

[image: сообщение]

Если закрыть лаунчер и пере открыть ручками, то всё ОК.

P.S.
Пользователь является админом.

Если пробовать таким же алгоритмом запустить лаунчер для версии 0.7.0.0, всё отрабатывает корректно.

Comment: А проще не получается, без P/Invoke?

Comment: Буду очень рад, если поделитесь другим способом запуска desktop приложения из под юзера SYSTEM!!!

Comment: Хм. Я не пробовал, но разве нельзя указать в [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) другого пользователя? Кража access token'а у winlogon не кажется мне хорошим решением.

Comment: SYSTEM не имеет доступ напрямую к desktop windows.

Comment: В общем, так и найдя решение, пришлось поменять архитектуру и отказаться от сервиса в пользу 
тонкого лаунчера к Task Manager + 
утилиты для обновления

:(

Comment: Жаль, решение было бы интересно многим. Надеюсь, в следующий раз вашему вопросу повезёт больше.